# Which email headers to setup when you want to send a high priority email?

Tags: email, smtp

I want a complete list of email headers to setup in order to get the message to appear as important in most mailing clients.

Answer (score 3):

```
Priority: Urgent
X-Priority: 1
Importance: high
```

You are welcome to improve the list, if you know others.

Comment: `Priority` is actually for MTA delivery policy.  Perhaps some clients also mark it as important, though.